# Jenkins and Git: Local Branch No Longer Referencing Corresponding Remote Branch

Tags: git, jenkins, git-branch

I need help understanding the following: I'm running a Jenkins job to build out a project hosted in a remote git repo. I am checking out code to a sub-directory, and checking out specific local branch "test-1.1." I have a corresponding remote branch as well.

However, when I run the Jenkins build, and run `git branch -av`, I get:

```
* test-1.1                        f10e15e Commit Text2
* remotes/origin/test-1.1         818da9e Commit Text1
```

When I manually perform a git clone, and checkout to branch test-1.1, `git branch -av` gives:

```
* test-1.1                        818da9e Commit Text1
* remotes/origin/test-1.1         818da9e Commit Text1
```

It appears that the Jenkins build is doing the branch checkout differently, but I'm not sure how or what.

How would I get Jenkins to checkout the "test-1.1" (or any other) branch and be at the correct hash, and retain the reference to its corresponding remote branch? I could write a shell script, but would there be any other way of doing this that I might be missing?

Jenkins 1.544 with Git 2.0 plugin, CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Jenkins does very, very odd stuff with git.  I've never understood it.  It seems to work, but the jenkins clone is always in a detached state.  It's like it gets the SHA-1 of the branch and checks that out, instead of checking the branch itself out.

Comment: Oddly, `f10e15e` is the hash for the `master-1.3` branch. I'm perplexed why it would arrive at that.

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, Jenkins git plugin has it's own way of managing the cloning and branches. But it does work. If you want to build branch test-1.1, you type that into the Jenkins job configuration and stop worrying. After the build is finished, you can check from the build page what was the sha of the commit that was built. If it's not what you expect, only then you should worry.

(I think the reason for the git plugin's peculiarities are that it is so versatile: It can build multiple branches in multiple repositories. Because of this it does not check out a branch, but it does build from whatever commit is the latest in the branch(es) you want to build.)

If you find it difficult to let go of complete control, you always have the option of configuring the job with no SCM and then you can type the commands to do cloning and branch checkout into the build step box.

Comment: If it was about control, I wouldn't be using Jenkins (-; I would like to understand this behavior so that I know what is happening with the checkouts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Below plugin will help you to parameterized git-hub check out ..see more below
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin

Comment: I'm not using git-hub. Could you provide an example of this plugin's usage?

Answer (score 0):

The option in the git scm 'Check out to specific local branch' does not do what you think it does (or what anyone would reasonably assume). It does not 'git checkout '. Instead, this is a post-processing step where the git plugin, *after* it checks out the commit it has determined to use, creates a new local branch with the name you specified in the option, based on the commit. It is entirely possible (and seems to be the case here) that the commit is for something completely different than the actual branch in the repository. All the option does is give a new local name to the commit that is checked out. You can put any name here, including unrelated existing branches or branches that don't exist.